# Pulling data out of CSV file into excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to get some data from .csv report file. There is and error in Set ClassBook, as what I am guessing this is only working with xls, or xlsx files.

The path is defined by user in cell and is in a format like C:\Folder\ and the rest of the code is then specifying the name of file, as this is changing every day.

```
Sub PullData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim PathFile As String
    PathFile = Cells(23, 15)

Dim ClassBook As Workbook
    Set ClassBook = PathFile & "class" & Format(Now() + 1, "ddmmyy") & "-booked.csv"

Dim Template As Workbook
    Set Template = ActiveSheet

    Sheets(Template).Cells(5, 15) = Sheets(ClassBook).Cells(2, 1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is this a new file or a file that exists that you are trying to open?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open an already existing file, use:

```
Dim ClassBook As Workbook, ClassSheet As Worksheet
Set ClassBook = Workbooks.Open(PathFile & "class" & Format(Now() + 1, "ddmmyy") & "-booked.csv")
Set ClassSheet = ClassBook.ActiveSheet
```

Additionally, further down in your code, it looks like you're assigning Template (which is `Dim`'d as a `Workbook` to `ActiveSheet`, which is a `WorkSheet`. You'll want to use this instead:

```
Dim Template As Worksheet
Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheetName") '<~ put the name of the sheet you want to use as a template here
```

Then, working our way down, you can write:

```
Template.Cells(5, 15) = ClassSheet.Cells(2, 1)
```

Finally, you could be more explicit in your `PathFile` assignment, which could save you some debugging down the line when a user inevitably does something you did not expect:

```
Dim PathFile As String
PathFile = Template.Cells(23, 15) '<~ use Template AFTER you set it as a worksheet
```

So, to wrap it all up, here's an example of how I might write this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub PullData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim PathFile As String
Dim ClassBook As Workbook
Dim ClassSheet As Worksheet, Template As Worksheet

'set references up-front
Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheetName")
PathFile = Template.Cells(23, 15).Value
Set ClassBook = Workbooks.Open(PathFile & "class" & Format(Now() + 1, "ddmmyy") & "-booked.csv")
Set ClassSheet = ClassBook.ActiveSheet

'do work
Template.Cells(5, 15) = ClassSheet.Cells(2, 1)

'do other stuff, like close the CSV file or save the Template etc...

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. How can I do that without actually opening the file?

Comment: I think you'll need to open the file @user3361013. If you'd prefer to not SEE it, you can use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (then set it back to `True` at the end of the script)